# @FontFace not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face

So I have this @fontFace rule

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myriadPro-Black';
    src: url("fonts/myriadPro-BlackCond.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

It works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. I understand that Firefox has different rules for fontface than other browsers, but I am having a hard time understanding. Getting used to cross browser optimization.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple extention's for wider support:**

How i generate my fontface rule's is by using a online generator.
It save's a lot of time as it write's everything in the good order.
Plus it make's sure you support a wide variety of different extentions.

*An example of such a generator can be found here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator*

**Security problem with firefox:**

FireFox has secured the @font-face. Firefox for example might throw a 301 error, saying you don't have permission of access to the font file and therefor not load it, while other browsers don't.

You could give the right permissions using .htaccess or whatever config file for the webserver you working on but since i use a variety of webservers this is annoying. What works best for me is placing the font file's in the same directory as the .css file.

So i have one external fonts.css file containing all the css font line's within the font directory. Then i can include this .css file on the page i would like to use this font. Make sure you don't make additional directory's so you can call the font without anny directory. In your example, placing the font file in your css directory and change the code to:

> @font-face {
>       font-family: 'myriadPro-Black';
>       src: url("myriadPro-BlackCond.otf") format("opentype"); }

*more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face*